# Reading and Writing files async in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Currently i'm reading and writing files asynchronously, the thing is that i'm not sure that all the line from the file were read before the rest of my code is executed, here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

//var str = fs.readFileSync("stockststs.json");



function updateJson(ticker) {
    //var stocksJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("stocktest.json"));
    fs.readFile('stocktest.json', function(error, file) {
        stocksJson =  JSON.parse(file);



        if (stocksJson[ticker]!=null) {
            console.log(ticker+" price : " + stocksJson[ticker].price);
            console.log("changin the value...")
            stocksJson[ticker].price =  989898;
            console.log("Price after the change has been made -- " + stocksJson[ticker].price);
             fs.writeFile('stocktest.json',JSON.stringify(stocksJson, null, 4) , function(err) {  
                            if(!err) {
                                console.log("File successfully written");
                            }


                       });
        }
        else {
            console.log(ticker + " doesn't exist on the json");
        }
    });
}


updateJson("APPL");
```

I'm wondering if there is any better way to to implement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its always a good practice to check in your callback for error. For example, i have written a small getCache function that checks if the file exists first, then tries to read that file and fire a callback afterwards

```
Cache.prototype.getCache = function(cache_filename, callback) {
    cache_filename = this.cache_foldername + cache_filename;
    fs.exists(cache_filename, function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fs.readFile(cache_filename, 'utf8', function (error, data) {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log('File: '+ cache_filename +' successfully Read from Cache!');
                    _.isObject(data) ? callback(null,data) : callback(null,JSON.parse(data));
                } else console.log("Error Reading Cache from file: " + cache_filename + " with Error: " + error);
            });
        } else callback(null,false);
    });
}
```

note that in here what you need to do is to write the file after it has been read and checked with the `if (!error)`

i hope this helps

Comment: Let's say that i want to run my function a few times it means it will read the file that write to it then it will happen again, so i've tried this and in the 2nd call it not writing to the file.. 
any idea why?

Comment: Yes because this function checks if the file exists first .. if you want to keep rewriting just remove that check

Comment: are you talking about my function ?
If yes which line should i remove?

Comment: I thought you reused my function .. Am checking now from my mobile. I will get back to you as soon as on my laptop

Comment: can you please share the updated code .. i guess the above code has been updated